# Is it possible to have more than 1 background image repeat

Tags: html, css, web

I know I can repeat a single background image in the y direction. But I want to repeat a few of them. I also want to resize them all so they fill the entire screen each. i.e. to give the effect of them being on top of each other.

I know I can use something like fullpage but I'd rather code it myself.

All I have is:

```
body {
       background: url("images/bg1.png");
       background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: `background: url(firstimage.jpg), url(second.jpg), ...` Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: You do understand that using `cover` means the image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. Which in your case is the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the image urls one after the other with their respective properties separated with a comma like this:

```
background: 
   url(1.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,
   url(2.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,
   url(3.png),
   url(4.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly example, however it shows a lot of different options:

```
body {
  background-image   : url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/),
                       url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/),
                       url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);

  background-repeat  : repeat-y,
                       repeat-x,
                       repeat-y;

  background-position: bottom right,
                       top left,
                       bottom left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/c7Lof03h/2/

Comment: Is it possible to have a series of <section></section> define each section to be 1 full screen in the CSS and then define a background for each?

Comment: Are you trying to over lap them?